# How to disable simulator build in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode7

I am using third-party libraries(.a) that do not support simulator. When I build I seem to be getting link errors in I386 code. How can I disable building for the 386 architecture?

Comment: I am running virtually (macincloud.com) and can't attach a device. What would be a solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

Set **Build Settings -> Architectures -> Supported Platforms** to "*iphoneos*" for the project (the default is "*iOS*", which includes both real hardware and the simulator).

You might have to limit the supported architectures too to match those shipped from the 3rd party.

Comment: This still seems like the correct answer for XCode 14.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this problem when I was using a library that was not written to support running on a simulator, It resulted in a lot of link errors stating that symbols were not recognized for i386 architecture. I discovered that if I selected an attached ios device instead of the simulator, the linker errors went away.

Comment: I am running virtually (macincloud.com) and can't attach a device. What would be a solution for me?

Comment: I am not familiar with macincloud.com Sorry

Comment: Just a mac someone is giving people remote access to.